# mutt read message change to unread messages

Tags: mutt

I'm using mutt:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ mutt -v
Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)
Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 5.9.20130511 (compiled with 5.9)
libidn: 1.28 (compiled with 1.28)
hcache backend: tokyocabinet 1.4.48
Compile options:
-DOMAIN
-DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  -USE_SETGID  -USE_DOTLOCK  -DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK   
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_SMTP  
-USE_SSL_OPENSSL  +USE_SSL_GNUTLS  +USE_SASL  +USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO  
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX  
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET  
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM  
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  +CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME  
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT  
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR  
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_LIBIDN  +HAVE_GETSID  +USE_HCACHE  
ISPELL="/usr/bin/hunspell"
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/usr/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
-MIXMASTER
To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
To report a bug, please visit http://bugs.mutt.org/.

[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

Is there a way to change old/read message to new (N) after it was read?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `toggle-new` command (`N` by default) seems relevant.

Comment: i could not find it, thank you for pointing this out for me)